# VueJs - Change div color with transition

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a header bar and a button. I can change the color on click but I want the color change with a smooth transition or effect on click. Is it possible to do it with *Vue.js*?

**HTML code**

```
<html>    
    <head>
      <title>My App</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <div class="head" :class="{ headnew : change }"></div>
            <button @click="changeIt">Change me!</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"> 
    </script>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
.head {
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #84CF6A, #16C0B0);
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

.headnew {
    background: red;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**JS code**

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        change : false
    },
    methods: {
        changeIt() {
            this.change = true
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background gradients cannot be animated, but you can hack it by fading in another element (the `::before` pseudo element in this case) that overlaps the background.

Here's a generic HTML+CSS example which you can easily adapt to your code:

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, blue, yellow);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

.box::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.2s linear;
}

.box:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Some text</div>
```

Comment: Yes that's what I need, but I expect the transition to be on the click of the button, I don't know if Vue can handle pesudo properties.

Comment: That's why I mentioned you need to adapt it to your situation (instead of `.box:hover` you'd use `.headnew`, for example). Your issue has nothing to do with Vue; the Vue code you have so far is fine. It's all about the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it simply by adding `transition` property to your `.head` as follow :

```
  .head {
  ...
    transition: background 6s ease;
   }
```

check the following working solution :

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      change : false
  },
  methods: {
      changeIt() {
          this.change = true
      }
  }
})
```

```css
.head {
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, #84CF6A, #16C0B0);
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transition: background 6s ease;
  }


.headnew {
    background: red;
    height: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
  <div id="app">
    <div class="head" :class="{ headnew : change }"></div>
    <button @click="changeIt">Change me!</button>
</div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
```